# firefox: error occurs when I test if cookies are enabled

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies

On my website , to see if the cookie are enabled, i import a document (.php) that use this code:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "Cookie_PROVA";
$cookie_value = "prova";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
      header('Location: cookies/cookie.html');
}
?>
```

This works in chrome, but in firefox and in Internet Explorer No. 
When I open the browser for the first time and with cookies enabled and I go on my site , the first time going up cookie.html if reloading my index page go on Index . But I should not go to cookie.html.
Ps cookie.html is a simple html page with error message!

Comment: if it is php then the page extension should be `.php` not `.html`

Comment: This code is located on a php page , in case of error go on a html page

Comment: What do you get when you execute: `print_r($_COOKIE);`

Comment: When i open the browser, cookie are enable and the list of cookie is empty... When i open my index page, in the browser open cookie.html but in the list of cookie, the new cookie is set

Comment: print_r($_COOKIE), print "Array()"...but in the list list of cookies, the new cookie is set!